# Dynamically load module with Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic, import

I know that there are several posts on this topic, however for what ever reason I can't get my head around it, or at least implement it. Below is some sample code of what I am trying to do.

**Base Class:**

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age

    def getAge(self):
        return self._age

    def speak(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def speak_twice(self):
        self.speak()
        self.speak()
```

**Sub Class**

```
from Animal import Animal
class Dog(Animal):
    def speak(self):
        print "woff!"
```

**Test Code**

```
mod = __import__("Dog")
spot = mod(5)
```

After running test Code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:~test.py", line 2, in <module>
    spot = mod(5)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

So basically my question is how do I load modules dynamically and initialize them correctly?

EDIT:

I will not know the subclass until runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the module itself, then get its class member.  You can't just import the class.  Assuming your subclass is in a file accessible from the pythonpath as 'animal':

```
mod = __import__('animal')
spot = mod.Dog(5)
```

When you import a module, the interpreter first looks to see if a module with that name exists in `sys.modules`, then if it fails to find it there, it searches over the pythonpath looking for a package or module matching the given name.  If and when it finds one, it parses the code therein, builds a module object out of it, places it on `sys.modules`, and returns the module object to the calling scope to be bound to the name it was imported with in the given namespace.  All the items in the module (classes, variables, functions) in the module scope (not nested inside something else in the code) are then available as members of that module instance.

Edit:

In response to your comment, the real problem is that you are trying to look up an attribute of the module dynamically, not that you are trying to import anything dynamically.  The most direct way to do that would be:

```
import sub_animal
getattr(sub_animal, 'Dog')
```

However, if you are trying to dynamically determine the class to initialize based upon some conditions, you probably want to read up on the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), and possibly [`decorator`s](http://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/a-primer-on-python-decorators/) or even [`metaclass`es](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), so that you can dynamically add subclasses automatically to the factory.

```
class AnimalFactory(type):

    animal_classes = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        new_class = super(AnimalFactory, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        AnimalFactory.animal_classes[name] = new_class
        return new_class

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            klass = cls.animal_classes[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError('No known animal %s' % name)
        return klass(*args, **kwargs)

class Animal(object):

    __metaclass__ = AnimalFactory

    def __init__(self, age):

        self.age = age

    def speak(self):

        raise NotImplementedError()

# As long as the file it is implemented in is imported at some point,
# the following can be anywhere

class Dog(Animal):

    def speak(self):

        return 'woof'

# And then to use, again, anywhere

new_animal = AnimalFactory.build('Dog', 5)
```

Comment: How about if I don't know the class member until runtime?

Comment: Try `spot = getattr(mod, 'Dog')(5)`

Comment: @Richard Then the problem you are dealing with isn't dynamic module loading, but dynamic attribute lookup.

Comment: @sr2222 Great! That helps a lot! Thanks for the extra resources. Obviously I am going to have to do a bit of reading to understand all the terminology. Many thanks.